# 100% in-memory HSQL database

Tags: logging, hsqldb, in-memory-tables

I have a Java application set up as a service to do data-mining against ~3GB of data every few hours.  I would like this to occur 100% in memory.  Ideally I want the application to be isolated from everything; I want it to construct the database, do the mining I need, and tear down the database when it's done.

However with HSQLDB, even when i use the "create memory table...." command, a log is written of all of the statements and the table is recreated the next time the application runs.

I'm doing a LOT of inserts, ~150k+, so this file will quickly grow in size.  I also don't care about reconstructing the database upon next run, so the logging is useless to me.

I could just delete the file when I'm done, but if possible I'd like to avoid having to write that much to the disk.

Is there a way to turn off this feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which log are you talking about?

Comment: and are you using Hibernate to create the tables? or JDBC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No problem, just open the database connection thus:

```
 Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:aname", "sa", "");
```

For more information, refer to the [HSQL docs](http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlDocsFrame.html).